# Are exponential functions fractals?

Tags: exponential-function, fractals

I have been trying to find fractals in some data I am working with and (using box-counting), I think I have found one. However, when I visualize the data, it looks like an exponential, which got me curious: Do exponential functions (i.e. $y<e^{-x}$) count as fractals?

It seems like they shouldn't be, but they are self-similar - cutting off the first bit and then scaling up produces the same graph - and a basic box-counting algorithm produces a fractal dimension.

[Here is a Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1n2KeyzZA1mXnzG93EEvCHz7r_QuU_56n?usp=sharing) with my exploration so far.

Comment: What is your definition of a fractal?

Comment: Your construction might lead to the same self similarity for a straight line - surely not a fractal by any definition.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I was under the impression the definition of fractal was something that was both self similar AND had a fractional dimension (through a method like box counting).

Comment: @BenMorris: There is no consistent definition in the literature, whatever you have in mind, you should spell out in full detail in your question. As for the fractional dimension (by which one usually means "different from topological dimension"), a smooth curve never has one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally... with this loose wording you will hardly get any precise answer.
I think fractal is not quite a formal math concept, it's an informal thing and allows different formalizations.

So here's one loose answer (just my basic opinion): exponential functions are not fractals, they are smooth functions which is quite the opposite of a fractal.

A fractal (in my basic understanding) is something that has this property: when you "zoom into it deeper and deeper and deeper", it never starts looking like a straight line (i.e. it keeps exhibiting a very complex graph/structure/pattern no matter how deep you "zoom into it").

Well, exponential functions are not that. When you zoom into its graph (in some small $\epsilon$ neighborhood), it starts looking like a straight line.

Comment: Actually, there is one very precise definition, due to Mandelbrot: A fractal is a metric space whose Hausdorff dimension is different from its covering dimension.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I wasn't aware, thank you.